# Retrieve online data and generate and xml output of it

Tags: windows, perl

The project requires to grep online data and generate an xml file of it. This is how the output should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE MetaIssue SYSTEM "http://schema.highwire.org/public/toc/MetaIssue.pubids.dtd"> 
<MetaIssue volume="306" issue="1"> 
  <Provider>Cadmus</Provider> 
  <IssueDate>January 1, 2014</IssueDate>  
  <PageRange>C1-C76</PageRange> 
  <TOC> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>Editorial Focus</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00342.2013</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>Review</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00281.2013</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>CALL FOR PAPERS | Stem Cell Physiology and Pathophysiology</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00156.2013</DOI> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00066.2013</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>Articles</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00130.2013</DOI> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00047.2013</DOI> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00070.2013</DOI> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00096.2013</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>Corrigendum</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.zh0-7419-corr.2014</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
  </TOC> 
</MetaIssue>
```

The output which I am getting is:

```
<!DOCTYPE MetaIssue SYSTEM "http://schema.highwire.org/public/toc/MetaIssue.pubids.dtd"> 
<MetaIssue volume="306" issue="1"> 
  <Provider>Cadmus</Provider> 
  <IssueDate>January 1, 2014 </IssueDate> 
  <PageRange>C1-</PageRange> 
  <TOC> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>Review</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00281.2013</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>CALL FOR PAPERS | Stem Cell Physiology and Pathophysiology</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00156.2013</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>Articles</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.00130.2013</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
    <TocSection> 
      <Heading>Corrigendum</Heading> 
      <DOI>10.1152/ajpcell.zh0-7419-corr.2014</DOI> 
    </TocSection> 
  </TOC> 
</MetaIssue>
```

The code I tried is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $path1 = $ARGV[0];
open(F6, ">meta_issue.xml");

print "Enter the URL:";
my $url = <STDIN>;
chomp $url;

print "Enter the Volume Number:";
my $vol = <STDIN>;
chomp $vol;

print "Enter the Issue Number:";
my $iss = <STDIN>;
chomp $iss;

my $website_content = get($url);

print F6 "\<\!DOCTYPE MetaIssue SYSTEM \"http://schema.highwire.org/public/toc/MetaIssue.pubids.dtd\">\n";
print F6 "<MetaIssue volume=\"$vol\" issue=\"$iss\">\n";
print F6 "<Provider>Cadmus</Provider>\n";

if ($website_content =~ m#<span class="highwire-cite-metadata-date">(.*?)</span>#s) {
    #<span class="highwire-cite-metadata-date">January 1, 2014 </span>

  print F6 "<IssueDate>$1</IssueDate>\n";    #<IssueDate>January 1,         2014</IssueDate>
}

if ($website_content =~ m#(<span class="label">:</span>\s?(.*?)(-(.*?))?</span>)#gs) {
    #.*?(?!<span class="label">:</span>\s?(.*?)(-(.*?))?</span>)$#gs)  #<PageRange>C1-C76</PageRange>

  my $first = $2;
  print F6 "<PageRange>$2-</PageRange>\n";
}

print F6 "<TOC>\n";

while ($website_content =~ m#<h2 id=".*?" class=".*?">(.*?)</h2>#gs) {
  my $h = $1;
  print F6 "<TocSection>\n";
  print F6 "<Heading>$h</Heading>\n";

  if ( $website_content =~ m#(.*?<p><span class="label">DOI:</span>\s?(.*?)\n?</p>\s?</span>\s?\n?</div>.*?)#gs ) {
    my $doi  = $1;
    my $doi1 = $2;
    print F6 "<DOI>$doi1</DOI>\n";
    print F6 "</TocSection>\n";
  }
}

print F6 "</TOC>\n</MetaIssue>\n";
```

**Note**: Each `<Heading>` might have one or more `<DOI>` values, which I am not able to retrieve

1. I cannot place the particular `<DOI>` values under that `<Heading>`.
2. I cannot retrieve the last occurrence of the digit from

   ```
   <span class="label">:</span>\s?(.*?)(-(.*?))?</span>
   ```

   since there are variation such as `</span> c14</span>` or `<span> c12-c14</span>`. So from here I need to grep the last digit i.e `c14`

I execute the code in cmd as follows;

```
    D:\Code>Perl File name (Enter) 
    Enter the URl: http://ajpcell.physiology.org/content/306/1 
    Enter the Volume Number: 306 
    Enter the Issue Number: 1
```

#### UPDATE:

In the URL's :

1) http://ajpendo.physiology.org/content/283/5

2) http://ajpendo.physiology.org/content/280/1

The DOI is not there, so in that case, the output in place of

```
      <DOI>$_</DOI> tag
```

should be

```
      <ResId type=”publisher-id”>$volume/$issue/$first_page</ResId>
```

where $first_page is specific to that particular section.

I added "else{} loop" in "sub retrieve_doi()" and also in the "for{} loop" below, but not getting the desired output .

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature qw{ say };
    use HTML::Parser;
    use WWW::Mechanize;

    my ($date, $first_page, $last_page, @toc);
    sub get_date {
      my ($self, $tag, $attr) = @_;
       if ('span' eq $tag
         and $attr->{class}
         and 'highwire-cite-metadata-date' eq $attr->{class}
         and not defined $date
          ) {
    $self->handler(text => \&next_text_to_date, 'self, text');

             } elsif ('span' eq $tag
                  and $attr->{class}
         and 'highwire-cite-metadata-pages' eq $attr->{class}
        ) {
    if (not defined $first_page) {
        $self->handler(text => \&parse_first_page, 'self, text');
    } else {
        $self->handler(text => \&parse_last_page, 'self, text');
    }

} elsif ('span' eq $tag
         and $attr->{class}
         and 'highwire-cite-metadata-doi' eq $attr->{class}
        ) {
    $self->handler(text => \&retrieve_doi, 'self, text');

} elsif ('div' eq $tag
         and $attr->{class}
         and $attr->{class} =~ /\bissue-toc-section\b/
        ) {
    $self->handler(text => \&next_text_to_toc, 'self, text');
}
}


sub next_text_to_date {
my ($self, $text) = @_;
$text =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
$date = $text;
$self->handler(text => undef);
}


sub parse_first_page {
my ($self, $text) = @_;
if ($text =~ /([A-Z0-9]+)(?:-[0-9A-Z]+)?/) {
    $first_page = $1;
    $self->handler(text => undef);
}
}


sub parse_last_page {
my ($self, $text) = @_;
if ($text =~ /(?:[A-Z0-9]+-)?([0-9A-Z]+)/) {
    $last_page = $1;
    $self->handler(text => undef);
  }
 }

sub next_text_to_toc {
my ($self, $text) = @_;
push @toc, [$text];
$self->handler(text => undef);
}

sub retrieve_doi {
my ($self, $text) = @_;
if ('DOI:' ne $text) 
{
    $text =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    push @{ $toc[-1] }, $text;
    $self->handler(text => undef);
}
else        #UPDATE
{
    $text =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    push @{ $toc[-1] }, $text;
    $self->handler(text => undef);
 }
 }

  print STDERR 'Enter the URL: ';
  chomp(my $url = <>);
  my ($volume, $issue) = (split m(/), $url)[-2, -1];

  my $p = 'HTML::Parser'->new( api_version => 3,
                         start_h => [ \&get_date, 'self, tagname, attr'    ],
                       );

  my $mech = 'WWW::Mechanize'->new(agent => 'Mozilla');
  $mech->get($url);
  my $contents = $mech->content;
  $p->parse($contents);
  $p->eof;

  my $toc;

for my $section (@toc) {
$toc .= "<TocSection>\n";
$toc .= "<Heading>".shift(@$section)."</Heading>\n";
$toc .= join q(), map "<DOI>$_</DOI>\n", @$section;
$toc .= join q(), map "<ResId type=”publisher-id”>$volume/$issue/$first_page</ResId>\n", @$section; #UPDATE
$toc .= "</TocSection>\n";
}

     open (F6, ">meta_issue_$issue.xml");

     print F6 <<"__HTML__";
     <!DOCTYPE MetaIssue SYSTEM "http://schema.highwire.org/public/toc/MetaIssue.pubids.dtd">
     <MetaIssue volume="$volume" issue="$issue">
     <Provider>Cadmus</Provider>
     <IssueDate>$date</IssueDate>
     <PageRange>$first_page-$last_page</PageRange>
    <TOC>
    $toc</TOC>
   </MetaIssue>
   __HTML__
```

Please let me know how to update the code to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proper module to parse the HTML:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use HTML::Parser;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my ($date, $first_page, $last_page, @toc);
sub get_info {
    my ($self, $tag, $attr) = @_;
    if ('span' eq $tag
        and $attr->{class}
        and 'highwire-cite-metadata-date' eq $attr->{class}
        and not defined $date
       ) {
        $self->handler(text => \&next_text_to_date, 'self, text');

    } elsif ('span' eq $tag
             and $attr->{class}
             and 'highwire-cite-metadata-pages' eq $attr->{class}
            ) {
        if (not defined $first_page) {
            $self->handler(text => \&parse_first_page, 'self, text');
        } else {
            $self->handler(text => \&parse_last_page, 'self, text');
        }

    } elsif ('span' eq $tag
             and $attr->{class}
             and 'highwire-cite-metadata-doi' eq $attr->{class}
            ) {
        $self->handler(text => \&retrieve_doi, 'self, text');

    } elsif ('div' eq $tag
             and $attr->{class}
             and $attr->{class} =~ /\bissue-toc-section\b/
            ) {
        $self->handler(text => \&next_text_to_toc, 'self, text');
    }
}


sub next_text_to_date {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    $text =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    $date = $text;
    $self->handler(text => undef);
}


sub parse_first_page {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    if ($text =~ /([A-Z0-9]+)(?:-[0-9A-Z]+)?/) {
        $first_page = $1;
        $self->handler(text => undef);
    }
}


sub parse_last_page {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    if ($text =~ /(?:[A-Z0-9]+-)?([0-9A-Z]+)/) {
        $last_page = $1;
        $self->handler(text => undef);
    }
}


sub next_text_to_toc {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    push @toc, [$text];
    $self->handler(text => undef);
}


sub retrieve_doi {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    if ('DOI:' ne $text) {
        $text =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
        push @{ $toc[-1] }, $text;
        $self->handler(text => undef);
    }
}


print STDERR 'Enter the URL: ';
chomp(my $url = <>);
my ($volume, $issue) = (split m(/), $url)[-2, -1];

my $p = 'HTML::Parser'->new( api_version => 3,
                             start_h => [ \&get_info, 'self, tagname, attr' ],
                           );

my $mech = 'WWW::Mechanize'->new(agent => 'Mozilla');
$mech->get($url);
my $contents = $mech->content;
$p->parse($contents);
$p->eof;

my $toc;
for my $section (@toc) {
    $toc .= "    <TocSection>\n";
    $toc .= "      <Heading>" . shift(@$section) . "</Heading>\n";
    $toc .= join q(), map "      <DOI>$_</DOI>\n", @$section;
    $toc .= "    </TocSection>\n";
}

print << "__HTML__";
<!DOCTYPE MetaIssue SYSTEM "http://schema.highwire.org/public/toc/MetaIssue.pubids.dtd">
<MetaIssue volume="$volume" issue="$issue">
  <Provider>Cadmus</Provider>
  <IssueDate>$date</IssueDate>
  <PageRange>$first_page-$last_page</PageRange>
  <TOC>
$toc  </TOC>
</MetaIssue>
__HTML__
```

### Basic explanation:

[HTML::Parser](http://p3rl.org/HTML::Parser) is callback-based, which means you give it subroutines to run when it encounters a given event in the parsed document. I use a general callback `get_info`, which searches for various indicators of needed information in the HTML. As we are often interested in something like "nearest text after the given span", it just registers the new callback for the text. For example, when the span with the class `highwire-cite-metadata-date` is found and date is not yet defined, it registers a new text handler, which would run `next_text_to_date`. The handler just assigns the text to the `$date` variable and removes the handler. I'm not sure that's the "correct" way to do it, but in this case at least, it works.

I used [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) in order to be able to specify the User Agent. With the default value of the much simpler [LWP::Simple](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Simple), I wasn't getting the whole HTML.

The output smells of a template. Switching to [Template](http://p3rl.org/Template) might be a good step forward.

Comment: [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize), [HTML::Parser](http://p3rl.org/HTML::Parser), [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub)...

Comment: Thanks @choroba..                                                                             The above code is working perfectly right, except that it showed error saying "Can't find string terminator" so that was rectified by deleting the unwanted space from _HTML_ and adding a blank line at the bottom after _HTML_.
**It would be great if you could explain the code and also let me know (or give some reference on) how to use subroutines...**